# SAPUI5 Filter Search

Tags: filtering, sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm Developing Fiori App with Master-Master-Detail template, 
First I'm filtering by date but I want to use the search box that it's generated by default.
I need to use both condition filters: Date and the element specified in serach box.
Somebody knows how to add search filter without remove previous filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filters are applied to the `ListBinding` and there is no official API to access to current filter objects. You could store the filters somewhere in your controller, but eventually, you'll need to call the `filter` method again with all the filters that you want to apply.